# Mongoose retrieve all documents that are not referenced in the same collection's array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the below `Post` schema. The post schema contains an array field that may contain other posts as replies. What I would like to do is retrieve all documents which are not referenced in any post's replies field. Basically get all posts that are not replies of an original post.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    creator: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        validate: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid, 'Creator ID is invalid']
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        validate: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid, 'Owner ID is invalid']
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Content is required'
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Like',
            validate: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid, 'Like ID is invalid']
        }
    ],
    replies: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Post'
        }
    ]
}, {
    autoCreate: true,
    timestamps: true
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', schema);

module.exports = Post;
```

I have tried using `$lookup` with `$match` & `$nin` but I cannot make it work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF I'm not mistaken this seems to work:

```
            let posts = await MODELS.Post.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'posts',
                        localField: '_id',
                        foreignField: 'replies',
                        as: 'references'
                    }
                },
                {
                    '$match': {
                        'references._id': {
                            '$exists': false
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    '$sort': {
                        createdAt: -1
                    }
                },
                {
                    '$project': { 
                        references: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    '$limit': 10
                }
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be easier to just update the schema to track either a) whether it's an original post or b) whether it's a reply. Then you can just do a query by that Boolean field rather than looping through a series of arrays.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm thinking too